# VSTO diagonal line in an Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, border, cell

I am currently trying to find a way using VSTO in C# for Excel, to draw a diagonal line in a cell using C# code. But i can't find anyone on the web who even tried to do this.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Thank you

(Excuse me for my bad english but it's not my language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manipulate borders as follows:

```
Excel.Range range = ... the cell(s) you want ...;

var border = range.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlDiagonalDown];
border.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin;
border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```

The `XlBordersIndex` enumeration specifies which border you want to update:

```
xlDiagonalDown
xlDiagonalUp
xlEdgeBottom
xlEdgeLeft
xlEdgeRight
xlEdgeTop
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not how in VSTO, but using COM you can do something like this:

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(BeginX, BeginY, EndX, EndY);

Comment: In fact, what  i am trying to do is possible using the borderline  property of the cell. But i don't know to do this programmatically